# Frame in a class appearing for a second

Tags: python, class, tkinter, frame

I am brand new to using Tkinter and I need help. I started to create a class that has a frame at the top of the main window and a frame at the bottom. When I call the class in the main driver's python file it is as if the frame doesn't exist. I colored the top blue and the bottom red to try to see anything but I only see some blue pop up for a second and then nothing and the same goes for the red in the bottom. I know I am making some sort of dumb mistake but I can't catch it. Any help would be greatly appreciated thank you.

```
from tkinter import *


class StockInventory:

    def __init__(self, master):
        master.title("Stock Inventory")
        master.geometry('{}x{}'.format(1250, 750))
        master.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)
        top_frame = Frame(master, height=100, width=1250, bg="blue")
        bottom_frame = Frame(master, height=550, width=1250, bg="red")
        top_frame.pack()
        bottom_frame.pack(side=BOTTOM)
        self.welcomeTitle = Label(top_frame, text="Welcome to the Inventory", bd=10, anchor=W)
        self.welcomeTitle.config(font=("Courier", 20))
        self.welcomeTitle.pack()
        self.status = Label(bottom_frame, text="Loading stock...", bd=1, relief=SUNKEN, anchor=W)
        self.status.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)
```

-----main.py------

```
from tkinter import *
from StockInventory import StockInventory

root = Tk()

inventory = StockInventory(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: A Frame with any child widgets will normally shrink to fit those widgets.  Your Frames are indeed visible, and colored as specified, they're just covered entirely by the Labels they contain.  To get a Frame's height and width to be honored even if they have children, call `.pack_propagate(False)` on them.

Comment: @jasonharper This was it. Thank you so much.